# Restructure data with Numpy

Tags: pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a data set looks like

```
A, B
x, 1
x, 4
x, 2
y, 3
y, 6
z, 3
```

I want to group column A and transform column B into 
`[[1,4,2], [3,6], [3]]`

Was wondering if there is a quick Numpy way to do it without looping though groups in Pandas. Thanks.

Comment: `df.groupby('A').B.agg(list).to_list()`

Comment: `df.groupby('A').B.agg(list)`

Comment: Notice the varying length of lists in `B`?  That's a good indicator that this is not a good `numpy` fit.  It doesn't have a `group` functionality.  As a first cut I'd go with list and `defaultdict` methods.